# How to connect to an SFTP server via a fixed outgoing port?

Tags: c#, sftp, openssh

I have a small application, a command line executable written in C#, that connects to different SFTP servers using the `Renci.SSHNet` library to download files.

The thing is that, at the request of the administrator of one of these servers, to connect to it I don't only need to connect to a specific port (something usual) but to do it from a specific port in the client.

Is there any way to code this in my exe to force the use of a specific port? As a last resort I suppose there is the possibility of talking to my network administrators to set up some rule in the router or something, but I would prefer my application to be responsible for this.

I came up with the idea that I could redirect the traffic using local port forwarding. To test this, I set up an SSH server on my development machine using OpenSSH and a test SFTP server with Rebex Tiny SFTP Server. I then opened an SSH connection to my machine and then tried to connect to the SFTP through the redirected port. Well, I managed to get the SSH ACK through the defined port `localPort` but the rest of the communication and transfer is done through any port that is free.

```
string sshSrv = "127.0.0.1"; // Local SSH server
string sshUser = "user";
string sshPass = "pass";
int sshPort = 22;

string sftpSrv = "192.168.1.120"; // SFTP test server
string sftpUser = "tester";
string sftpPass = "password";
uint sftpPort = 2222;

string localSrv = "127.0.0.1";
int localPort = 51000;  // The outgoing traffic must go through this port.

ConnectionInfo sshCI = new ConnectionInfo(sshSrv, sshPort, sshUser, 
                        new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(sshUser, sshPass));

using (SshClient sshClient = new SshClient(sshCI))
{
    ForwardedPort fwdPortL = null;
    try
    {
        sshClient.KeepAliveInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);
        sshClient.Connect();

        fwdPortL = new ForwardedPortLocal(localSrv, (uint)localPort, sftpSrv, sftpPort);
        fwdPortL.Exception += delegate (object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ForwardedPortLocal Exception: " + e.Exception.ToString());
        };
        fwdPortL.RequestReceived += delegate (object sender, PortForwardEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Request Received: {e.OriginatorHost}:{e.OriginatorPort}");
        };
        sshClient.AddForwardedPort(fwdPortL);
        fwdPortL.Start();
                    
        using (SftpClient sftpClient = new SftpClient(localSrv, localPort, sftpUser, sftpPass))
        {
            sftpClient.Connect();
            // Stuff to test SFTP connection...
            sftpClient.Disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        fwdPortL?.Stop();
        sshClient.Disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid there's no public API for this in SSH.NET. You would have to mock the `ISocketFactory`. Also, a requirement to use a specific local port is quite strange.

Comment: Or you could fork SSH.NET and modify the socket creation code. It is pretty strange to require a particular outgoing port, no firewall I know of normally requires this. A transparent NAT router is probably your easiest option, assuming you can find one that you can force over a particular outgoing port.

Comment: According to https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/issues/1095 this seems to be not exacly easy to implement.